# Can a familiar learn languages from ranks in linguistics?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, familiars

According to RAW on familiars for Wizard/Sorcerer/Witch

> Skills: For each skill in which either the master or the familiar has ranks, use either the normal skill ranks for an animal of that type or the master's skill ranks, whichever is better. In either case, the familiar uses its own ability modifiers. Regardless of a familiar's total skill modifiers, some skills may remain beyond the familiar's ability to use. Familiars treat Acrobatics, Climb, Fly, Perception, Stealth, and Swim as class skills.

So, if the Wizard/Sorcerer/Witch gains a skill point in linguistics, so does the familiar.

Can the familiar learn to speak common (or any other language) in this way?

Comment: I think I've seen official clarification somewhere, but I can't find it at the moment, so have a comment instead.  The "...some skills may remain beyond the familiar's ability to use." phrase applies to Linguistics, preventing most familiars from *speaking* languages they learn, but nothing prevents a familiar with Int 3+ and skill points to devote to Linguistics from learning and being able to *understand* languages.  If a familiar can speak, though (such as a raven), it should be able to use its languages to full effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Speaking, No. Understanding, Maybe.

The few Familiars that can automatically speak, do so *"as a supernatural ability."*

From [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar):

> **Familiar Basics**
>
> Skills:
>   [...] Regardless of a familiar's total skill modifiers, some skills may remain beyond the familiar's ability to use.

and further down that page:

> **Intelligent Animals**
>
> Increasing an animal's Intelligence to 3 or higher means it is smart enough to understand a language. However, unless an awaken spell is used, the animal doesn't automatically and instantly learn a language, any more than a human child does. The animal must be taught a language, usually over the course of months, giving it the understanding of the meaning of words and sentences beyond its trained responses to commands like "attack" and "heel."
>
> Even if the animal is taught to understand a language, it probably lacks the anatomy to actually speak (unless awaken is used). For example, dogs, elephants, and even gorillas lack the proper physiology to speak humanoid languages, though they can use their limited "vocabulary" of sounds to articulate concepts, especially if working with a person who learns what the sounds mean.

So, to expand my answer a little... No they can't *speak* it, *unless* the animal has the right anatomy to produce speech. They *can* be taught to *understand* languages, though.

(You could argue that the gaining of a point of Linguistics reflects the months of learning a language, so that being Awakened is not a requirement.)

Familiars automatically meet the Intelligence requirement:

> **Familiar Ability Descriptions**
>
> All familiars have special abilities (or impart abilities to their masters) depending on the master's combined level in classes that grant familiars, as shown on the table below. The abilities are cumulative.
>
> `Master Class Level    Natural Armor Adj.  Intelligence
>   1st–2nd                 +1                  6
>   ...`

Comment: How does this affect "improved familiars"? Many of those familiars already _do_ have language skills.

Comment: So your answer is No... but the expanded answer is maybe yes?  Perhaps change your bolded first line to accurately reflect the answer?

Comment: @briddums The question asked about speaking, not understanding.

Comment: Familiars are magical beasts, not animals.  The intelligent animals limiter doesn't apply.

Comment: What if they actually do have the right anatomy, as in the case of ravens and parrots?